# Wrong result in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

When I use the statement

```
select Name, Id
from employee
where Id in (1234,1234,NULL);
```

I am getting the correct result. However, When I write the query

```
select Name, Id
from employee
where Id not in (1234,5678,NULL);
```

I am simply getting "empty set" as the result. Please tell me why this is happening. I am using MYSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Because comparing with `null` results in *unknown*. You have to use the `IS` operator with `null`

```
select Name, Id 
from employee 
where Id not in (1234,3456)
and Id is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, comparing anything with `NULL` evaluates to `UNKNOWN` (a third logical state besides `TRUE` and `FALSE`. To expand your two expressions:

1. `Id in (1234,1234,NULL)` => `Id = 1234 or Id = 1234 or Id = NULL` => `Id = 1234 or Id = 1234 or UNKNOWN`

   `TRUE or <anything>` evaluates to `TRUE`, so if `Id = 1234` returns
   `TRUE`, the whole expresison is `TRUE`
2. `Id not in (1234,5678,NULL)` => `Id != 1234 and Id != 5678 and Id != NULL` => `Id != 1234 and Id != 5678 and UNKNOWN`

   `<anything> and UNKNOWN` evaluates to `UNKNOWN`, so for no rows will the condition evaluate to `TRUE`, thus no rows returned